# Magento form validation for county

Tags: magento-1.9

Currently, no space is allowed in the county input field.

Where can I change this, so that I can include a space for county?

Comment: where is the country input filed appearing. If it's in the registration form or checkout the countries should be in a select field.

Comment: It's county not country, Mohit Humar channged it for some reason

Comment: OK. I've just checked on my registration page and checkout and it allows spaces in the county field. You must have some custom validation going on somewhere.